# Access json object value

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a this code in asp.net ashx file:

```
jsonString="{'id':'54','name':'reza'}";
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var a = j.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(object));
```

and get Json string and convert to 'a' object,How can i get value of a ?
for example i need get id field value into [id,54] ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify a strongly-typed target type for the deserialization (other than `object`), `JavaScriptSerializer` will return a `Dictionary<string, object>` and you'll have to access it as follows:

```
string jsonString = "{'id':'54','name':'reza'}";
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic data = j.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(object));
string id = data["id"]; // equals 54
```

Yet, you better define your own custom type to access the deserialized data. Something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

string jsonString = "{'id':'54','name':'reza'}";
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Person person = j.Deserialize<Person>(jsonString);
string id = person.id; // equals 54
```

Comment: +1 Worth noting that the string does *not* contain valid JSON. It does contain valid JavaScript, though, which I assume the serializer is happy to work with.

Comment: @Behzad Razzaqi, Care to explain why did you un-accept? Is it no longer valid?